# Full Calendar issue

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to use full calendar premium resource timeline feature in salesforce LWC component. There is updated version library bundle of fullCalendar 6.1.7, so i downloaded it's bundle and upload in salesforce static resource and imported it in LWC component. When loading the component in a page so its showing "FullCalendar: undefined" error in console.

i tried with importing the that bundle and the with the other one with npm install an dloaded its plugins by static resources in salesforce.